# Can I root my Samsung Galaxy s5 900V running lollipop?

Tags: rooting, 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-5, macos

I'm running lollipop on my Samsung Galaxy s5 900V Verizon model. I can't find a way to root. Anyone have any ideas? Also, I'm running a mac so any instructions there would be great. Thanks!

Also, Im worried about trying to root without a full backup. Ironically, getting full backup by rooting my phone is one of the reasons I want to do it. Any way I can do a full backup of my phone without root before I try?

Comment: Here, [full backup of non-rooted devices](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices).